# Remember scroll position in Chrome

Tags: chrome

I've been looking for a way to remember the last scroll position of a page when it's reloaded, eg:
When you read some paragraphs of an article, close the tab and visit the page again, you're redirected to your last position. 
Is there a way to do that? and if not, is it doable? (remember scroll position when the user closes the tab)

Comment: You can do this using some code and adding the page to bookmarks. For example when I right click on "about us" on this page and then inspect I can find     <div id="sometext" ...>. Let's say id is "footer". Add "footer" to the address bar: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39320/remember-scroll-position-in-chrome#footer Then press enter and bookmark this page. That's what I do. Click the link I gave to see what happens. This might not work on all websites because id tag is needed.

Comment: @onurcano22 Yeah, you don't always have a div id for where you left. And that's a manual solution, not really what I want.